# Set all components in java bold/italic

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I'm currently making a calculator using netbeans using jFrame.
My question is there a way where I can make all the text in my calculator bold or italic with a press of a button?

And if so can someone point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the font using the `setFont()` method.

Eg :

```
jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trajan Pro",3, 18));
```

Syntax: 
 Component.setFont(new jawa.awt.Font(font name(String),style(int),size(int)));

```
     Component A[]=this.getContentPane().getComponents();
     int y = A.length;
     for(int i=0;i<y;i++){
     System.out.println(A[i]);
     A[i].setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trajan Pro",3, 18));
     }
```

A is the array of all the components. Using for loop you can change for all components.

Comment: Do I have to manually list every single component?

How do refer to all my components at once?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to specify each place you want the change to happen. Refer to http://www.java-examples.com/create-bold-and-italic-font-example

You can have all the elements in an ArrayList or an Object Array to do this. Your choice.